# Mentioning US visa refusal in UK visit visa application

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I am asking too many questions recently so bear with me :D. My wife was refused L1B-blanket few years ago. She will be mentioning it in her application. I need advice on what details to provide in "give more details on what happened" section. As in, the refusal letter mentions refusal reason as "not clearly approvable." Just mentioning that much is enough?

Also, she holds USA B1/B2 visa and has traveled to USA twice on it, once before L1B rejection and once after. She has mentioned her USA travel history in appropriate section but is it worthwhile to point out this again (that she still holds USA B1/B2 visa) while mentioning that L1B was refused?

She otherwise has extensive travel history visiting 7-8 different countries so I am hoping US L1B rejection won't come in way of UK visitor visa which is for tourism purpose!

Comment: Why was she "clearly not approvable?" Those words sound more like the failure to meet an underlying, basic requirement for the visa, and less like the visa officer's judgment call on a could-go-either-way matter. Posting a scan of the refusal letter (with personal info obscured) might help us respond.

Comment: Sorry, I typed it wrong. It is "not clearly approvable" and not "clearly not approvable". Both different meanings. "Not clearly approvable" is more of a generic reason they provide without going into details. It may be that they feel the person isn't specialized enough and especially is single (she was that time) and doesn't own property etc, is potential immigrant.

Comment: Thanks. But things are still unclear: the L1-B "blanket" is a wide-coverage application filed by the _company_, not by the company's individual employees. If the L1-B blanket was refused, it is the company's responsibility to address the refusal. If, on the other hand, your wife's L1-B application was refused, then we'd presume it was because the company didn't name or individualize her correctly, or her paperwork was somehow incomplete. Which application was refused? What actually occurred will affect how she should complete the UK visa application.

Comment: It was my wife's application, which was under L1-B blanket which was refused. Nothing specific was mentioned apart from "not clearly approvable." Do we need to mention it in that case?

Comment: She should say she applied under her company's L1-B blanket, and her application was refused.

Comment: OK thanks. I hope this won't be negative since we are going to UK on tourism and she has long tourism travel history, including currently holding US B1/B2 visa. Should we mention about US B1/B2 visa after specifying L1B application was refused?